# Search values from one sheet to another sheet and paste the findings

Tags: excel, vba

I am just a beginner in vba and trying to build a macro to find values and paste the result. The requirement is I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets. So from worksheet named as    "TRS" under column product ID there are few values which I have to search one by one in sheet named as "AP" and when values found I have to copy the highlighted number situated below the value and paste in sheet "TRS" under column "offshore". I am trying to use loop and make the macro work. I have done some research and below is the code that I worked on but I am unable to get the value from sheet AP and  paste the sheet TRS under offshore column. It would be a great help if you can guide me where I am going wrong.

I have attached the picture of excel sheets and code of reference

[image: AP]

[image: TRS]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1):

Search the AP sheet for the ID using [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) and if found use `.Offset(1)` to get the value in the cell below.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub test2()

    Const COL_ID = "A"
    Const COL_OFFSHORE = "H" ' 8
    Const COL_FOUND = "O" '15
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsTRS As Worksheet, wsAP As Worksheet
    Dim fnd As Range, ID As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTRS = wb.Sheets("TRS")
    Set wsAP = wb.Sheets("AP")
    
    With wsTRS
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_ID).End(xlUp).Rows
    
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            ID = Trim(.Cells(i, COL_ID))
            Set fnd = wsAP.UsedRange.Find(ID & " -*", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If fnd Is Nothing Then
                .Cells(i, COL_FOUND) = "Not Found"
            Else
                .Cells(i, COL_FOUND) = "Found"
                .Cells(i, COL_OFFSHORE) = fnd.Offset(1)
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next

    End With
    MsgBox n & " IDs matched out of " & lastrow - 1, vbInformation
End Sub
```